# Google Sheets formula find highest or average from different sheets based on name

Tags: google-sheets, count, max, average, google-query-language

[image]

Hello stackoverflow, i want to fill  cell on Sheet B based on Sheet A data. i tried some guide "Max If (Max Value with Condition)" but its doesnt work give 0 (zero) value instead.

thank you

Comment: sure, the main sheets is here [link]https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/19vjbpBGhBAdzpAzb-tzWA3lGGAZJD2pY1pOWr7bMKec/edit?usp=sharing the screenshot just for an example, "1-20" and "leaderboard" sheets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=QUERY(SheetA!B:G; "select B,max(G),avg(G) where G matches '^[0-9]+' group by B")
```

[image]

Comment: sorry im not good on excel/sheets formula, maybe i type it wrong, but its give "blank" and auto-fill "name" below the formula cell

Comment: @YoonJunho here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1hMj3rjTrbcVpfhNSL_hPSy2X5BzS2PQpNPRQpsI-tZs/edit#gid=0

Comment: big thanks bro !! all good now he even duplicated my main sheets and make it all work so goood!!